# Apply Style in custom view where layout root tag is merge

Tags: android-layout, android-custom-view, android-styles, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I have a `TextInputLayout` with a custom Style that needs to be heavily reused so I am trying to turn it into a custom view.

Here is xml to be reused :

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

`TextInputLayoutAppearance` is the custom style I have created in the `styles.xml`

Here is the Class for my custom view :

```
 class OutlinedTextInput @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : TextInputLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_outlined_textinput, this, true)
    }
}
```

Here is the `view_outlined_textinput` I have adapted from the original xml above, for the custom view :

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:parentTag="com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</merge>
```

There are **2** things to notice here :

1. The layout uses a merge tag to avoid redundant view in the view hierarchy.
2. It is crucial to apply the custom style. The style is applied in the original xml  using style= syntax. However, since the merge tag is being used for the custom view it cannot be done that way.

I tried setting the style as follows but it didn't work :

```
class OutlinedTextInput @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = R.style.TextInputLayoutAppearance
) : TextInputLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
```

I assume the above solution should work as the 3rd parameter in the constructor is to pass in the style.

Another option is to set all the properties programatically in the `init {}` of my custom view but that defeats the purpose of having declared a style in the Styles file.

What are my options ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there are 4 constructor for a view

1. public View (Context context) -> Simple constructor to use when creating a view from code.
2. public View (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) -> Constructor that is called when inflating a view from XML
3. public View (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) -> Perform inflation from XML and apply a class-specific base style from a theme attribute.
4. public View (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) **Added in API level 21**

The 3rd & 4th constructors are called by subclasses if they want to specify an attribute containing a default style, or a default style directly (in the case of the four-argument constructor)

> For example, a Button class's constructor would call this version of the super class constructor and supply R.attr.buttonStyle for defStyleAttr; this allows the theme's button style to modify all of the base view attributes (in particular its background) as well as the Button class's attributes. [from the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#View(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int))

So, when you are creating your custom view and adding that view into an XML android will always call the second constructor which look like this under the hood

```
public TextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, attr.textInputStyle);
}
```

The third argument `attr.textInputStyle` is getting that specific style directly from the application theme.

So, To achieve the result you are looking for you can do the following.

1. In your `attrs.xml` add `<attr name="attribute_name" format="reference" />`

eg. **attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<attr name="attribute_name" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

2. Add in your AppTheme in the file `style.xml` `<item name="attribute_name">@style/your_style</item>`

eg. **style.xml**

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    ...
    <item name="attribute_name">@style/your_style</item>
     ...
</style>
```

3. Finally, in your custom view second constructor you pass that attribute as a parameter

   ```
   constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : 
     super(
           context,
           attrs,
           R.attr.attribute_name
          )
   ```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Worked! Thank you

Comment: This is for the theme level settings, what if I want to provide style to the view in a particular layout?

Comment: @JimitPatel you can use constructor #4 and provide a defStyleRes (i.e. R.style.MyStyle)